# Web is external and client side application, how to make ajax call to reach internal App Server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, cross-domain, n-tier-architecture

We have this architecture:

Web Server: Web Application is deployed (html, javascript, css)

Application Server: WebApi is deployed

Problem is , I cannot make ajax request to reach Application Server because its **behind firewall**.

The Web Application is supposed to be used publicly to the internet users.

What changes should we do to make it work?

Should we move our Web Application to Application Server? But how would this be accessible on internet.

Thanks in advance for suggestions/advice.

Comment: you should move your web api to your web server and then have web server communicate with application server through firewall exception.

Comment: @deezg if I move webapi to Web Server, then why would we need to have Application server anymore, webapi can directly talk to Database server right? That brings up the question, why do we need Application Server, I mean the purpose?

Comment: i've put comments into answer as they were too long for comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to put an exception in the firewall for the address of your web server... that way your web server can access the API but nothing else can (well, not quite nothing else - other stuff on that web server can but that can easily be solved by having your web app hosted on it's own/dedicated web server).

Comment: I believe they already have this exception, as I mentioned below in the comments, we could access API through C# using URL (http://IP addres... ) But right now, we are building complete client side application,i.e. pure Javascript, html and css. And we need to make ajax calls to API

Comment: The language (C# of javascript) won't make a difference. In both cases, you need to make http requests in order to access the API. If your SPA can't access the API then it is highly unlikely that they already have such an exception configured... but probably best to troubleshoot that with your IT guys if you think such an exception has already been configured but you're still having issues with connectivity.

Comment: I created a Web API using MVC and published it, which generated folders (areas,content,etc.) and files (web.config,packages.config, etc.). I have an internal IIS site, http://myweb:122 which i can access locally but how do i also make it available outside of our network?

Answer (score 1):

If your Web Application makes direct calls to the Web API endpoint (e.g. is a single page application that use a client-side javascript framework like AngularJS and/or it uses AJAX calls to your application server address), there is no way for your clients to access your API if you do not allow public access to your application server.

That's because your client resides inside your users web browsers.

You have to allow incoming connections to your Application Server through internet in your firewall.

Comment: You are absolutely right, its SPA using AngularJS deployed on Web server and need to access WebApi resides on Application server. I spoke to our Network team, and they cannot make it available to the internet for security reasons and similarly the Database server. 
We have one more application which is built on Asp.Net and though C# we make Service calls to App Server (WebApi) directly with no issues. But in this case, we are writing complete client side app (SPA) and wants to access WebApi using Ajax calls

Comment: I created a Web API using MVC and published it, which generated folders (areas,content,etc.) and files (web.config,packages.config, etc.). I have an internal IIS site, http://myweb:122 which i can access locally but how do i also make it available outside of our network?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it all depends on how you look at things and how distributed your application should be (criteria like load, security). 
In general, Web API might be just one more client (from your applications server perspective).

On the other hand, in robust/distributed system, you would have Web API only as an endpoint (controllers, mappers and things like that) that your mobile/ajax clients send requests to and then Web API communicates to Application server (where your business logic is).

Having Web API communicate to DB directly is not a good idea because  as you add clients to application server (mvc, web api, services, etc...) then you have as many db access points as you have clients. So, its a code maintenance problem plus a problem of your view tier being aware of DB.

Ideally, you need Application server as a tier where all your business logic is and its the one that all your clients target (mvc web app, web api, desktop, services, etc...) and that is the one that should communicate to your DAL. Also, then you can set firewall rules on your application server to allow incoming traffic from trusted sources (your other servers) instead from the whole internet (ajax).